# Can not setContentView with layout resource file

Tags: android, android-layout

A Package named "ui" is created in the package layout, and the layout resource file "my_listview.xml" is put in the package "ui". I would like to `setContentView` with "my_listview.xml" in the `MainActiviy.java`, but failed. What's the problem here? Any help will be appreciated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_listview);
...
}
```

**Edit**

If i put "my_listview.xml" is put in the package "layout", `setContentView(R.layout.my_listview);` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should place all xml files in directories they belong, not in your custom directories. Names of directories in res directory has meaning.
For example, resources layout-mdpi will be used if user has phone with medium dpi screen. Same thing with all other dirs. 
You should read this,it is helpfull: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the import statement of your activity.might be you had import android.R and not the R file of your project.

Comment: I import com.myproject.myproject.R;

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your `my_listview.xml` directly inside your layout folder in your project instead of putting it under the package ui.

Comment: plz check my edit in the post. It works fine when i pu the file inside the layout folder.

Comment: Ya, after posting my answer only i noticed your edit..Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Put that xml file in both the packages(folders[ui & layout]) it will work fine..

Else let me know!!

Comment: layout folder is enough!compiler doesn't recognize ui folder